# Mapbox Unity SDK: storying and displaying short relative distances

Tags: unity-game-engine, geolocation, mapbox, geospatial

I was wondering how I can go about storing and displaying small, but geographically accurate distances in the mapbox unity SDK?

I'm storing radius' about markers on a map, I get the value in meters (from ~0.5m-10m), and then, adaptively with the zoom level, I want to accurately display those meters in Unity world space (draw an ellipse) using these stored values. The problem is that the mapbox api from my understanding only lets you to convert lat/long to unity world coordinates and I'm running into precision errors. I can get adequate precision when using the `CheapRuler` class and meters, but as soon as I use the `_map.GeoToWorld(latlon)` method the precision is lost.

How would I go about keeping adequate precession, is there a way I can use the marker as the reference point and the radius as the offset, and get the relative unity world coordinate distance (of the radius) that way? I know you can also store scale relative to the mapbox tiles, but I'm not sure how I can convert that back to a unity world distance. I'm operating on very small distances, so any warping due to lat/long being a Mercator projection can probably be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a round-about solution.

First I convert the meters into unity world space using whatever `IMapScalingStrategy` Mapbox is currently using.
Then I convert from world to the view space of whatever camera I want to scale to the given bounds.

After that, I use find out the scale of the bounds, solving for:
UnityRelativeScaleChange = 2<sup>Map Zoom Level Change</sup>; which (to my estimations) is the relationship between unity scale and mapbox zoom levels.

This solutions works great as long as you don't have to zoom in/out by too much, otherwise you'll run into precision problems as the functions rely on the relative view-based size of a given bounds to do their calculations which will lead to unstable results if those initially take a tiny portion of the screen.